# Permission errors on several stored procedures in shrpnt_srch_srvc database

Tags: 2010, permissions, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I'm seeing the following error message from Sharepoint:

```
EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'proc_MSS_GetConfigurationProperty'
```

This is being thrown by `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.ManagedSqlSession.ExecuteNonQuery()`

I'm not a SharePoint pro, however I am a DBA, and am under the impression that Sharepoint should likely be managing permissions itself.

Permissions currently assigned to the proc:

```
+-----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+
| SPSearchDBAdmin | DATABASE_ROLE | OBJECT_OR_COLUMN | proc_MSS_GetConfigurationProperty | ALTER    | GRANT    |
|                 |               |                  |                                   |          |          |
| SPSearchDBAdmin | DATABASE_ROLE | OBJECT_OR_COLUMN | proc_MSS_GetConfigurationProperty | EXECUTE  | GRANT    |
+-----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------------------------------+----------+----------+
```

The `SPSearchDBAdmin` role has no members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the error you will see which services account is complaining about it. i am sure it should be search services account.

In order to resolve the issue please assign the SPSearchDBAdmin role permissions to that search services account.

http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2014_01_01_archive.html

Comment: Thanks - that resolved the issue after they rebooted.  I'm assuming SharePoint typically would have configured that role membership automatically?

Comment: @HannahVernon Which server did they reboot? Just the DB or the Search and the Apps too?

Comment: It would be the Sharepoint servers that were rebooted, not SQL Server